# Get all results from within the hour

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, php-carbon

I'm trying to get all results within the hour. NOT THE PAST HOUR, but WITHIN THE HOUR.

For example, if it's currently 12:30, I want to get all results since 12:00, not 11:30. Or if it's 6:45, I want to get all results since 6:00, not 5:45.

How can I do this using Carbon and Laravel?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$user = User::where('created_at', WHAT DO I PUT HERE)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know, you're looking for a Carbon solution. For readability and portability reasons below a native OOP PHP DateTime solution.

```
$user = User::where('created_at', '>=', (new DateTime)->format('Y-m-d H:00:00'))
->get();
```

Notice the >= operator!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Carbon's](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) `now()` and `subHour()` methods:

```
$user = User::where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subHour())->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple PHP [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function as

```
$user = User::where('created_at', '>', date('Y-m-d H:00:00'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to get current hour with no minute and second. Then run a query to return result after that time.

```
$currentHourInt = Carbon::now('Asia/Dhaka')->hour; 
$currentHour = Carbon::createFromTime($currentHourInt,0,0);

$user = User::where('created_at','>',$currentTime)
            ->get();
```

In the above example `$currentHourInt` will return the integer value of current time. Example, if it is `13:54:12` it will return `13`. I used `Aisa/Dhaka` as my timezone you can use yours or leave it blank if your data saved in `UTC` time. The `$currentHour` creates current time with current hour, 0 min and 0 sec. Example, if it is `13:54:12` it will return `13:00:00`.

For more information about Carbon: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [whereBetween](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereBetween) method for this.

```
User::whereBetween('created_at', [date('Y-m-d H:00:00'), date(Y-m-d H:i:s)])->get();
```